# How can I solve this error? Firebase App Check invalid token

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I am implementing app check in android flutter but I am encountering this error,

[image]

I have tried with physical devices but I have had no solution.

I tried it this way  :

```
if (kDebugMode) {
  
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
  );
} else {
 
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider:
        AndroidProvider.playIntegrity, 
  );
}
```

And this way

```
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug, );
```

and I tried it this way

```
FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
```

I have it registered in my App Check console

[image]

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  Please either translate your question or try [es.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.